# Tron blockchain : Filters not working on get events

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, contract, tron

**Trying to apply filter on contract event But it always return all records seems like filter not working.**

```
        this.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        {
          eventName: "InvoiceLog",
          filters: { '_invoiceId': id.toString()},
        }
      ).then((result: any) => {
        console.log("result of testing",result);
        // CommonModel.updateInvoicebal(result._invoiceId,result.currentBalance,result._toCurrentBalance);
        return result;
      });
```

Also tried with TronGrid but get same results.

**Case**: There are multiple event logs, I want to get single record by applying filter. In this, We have applied index on "_invoiceId". Now I am trying to get 1 result out of 1000 records.But it always send me multiple records.

It should provide 1 record as per filter applied.